# RTK Query With Next JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am struggling to get my head around **NEXT JS** with **RTK Query** I'm trying to share data with multiple pages I just want one place where the data is added to the store so I am not making multiple calls.

I want to call the query once and then access the data from all over the site. apose to calling it multiple times on different pages?

I can't have it called on one page because the user might navigate to the other page where it has not been fetched yet

**what is the best way to do it?**

in the next docs it says you can override the _app https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app BUT I won't be able to use the RTK Query hooks in that.

[image]

Comment: Is this for client-side next or a SSR/SSG scenario?

Comment: client-side rendering. I could not use the RTKQ hooks in SSR/SSG

Comment: For client-side, the `next-redux-wrapper` (or just wrapping your `App` in `Provider`) should already pretty much do it.
For SSR support, please wait for the next version of RTK.

Comment: I do that. But that doesn't prevent me have to repeat calls to an api on different pages

Comment: What exactly do you need to repeat?

Comment: "but I won't be able to use the RTK Query hooks in that" - Can you clarify why you can't use RTK Query hooks in the custom `_app`?

Comment: @phry Has SSR support been made available on rtk query yet?

Comment: @H.b https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/server-side-rendering

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this fits your use case since it won't refetch data when page refreshed, but you can do it by persisting data on local storage of browser. Then, on page load, you can check if data exist and decide if you want to use it or fetch new one.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

Answer (score 0):

In next13 you should initiate your RTK query API calls with the dispatch function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const result = dispatch(api.endpoints.getOrders.initiate("Orders"));
    return result.unsubscribe;
}, [dispatch]);
```

Then you can just retrieve the data from the store:

```
  const orders = useAppSelector(api.endpoints.getOrders.select("Orders"));
```

My full component looks like this:

```
"use client";

import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "@/app/store/hooks";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { api } from "@/app/store/api";

export default function Page() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { data: session, update } = useSession();
  useEffect(() => {
    const result = dispatch(api.endpoints.getOrders.initiate("Orders"));
    return result.unsubscribe;
  }, [dispatch]);
  const orders = useAppSelector(api.endpoints.getOrders.select("Orders"));

  console.log(orders);
  return (
    <main>
    ...
    </main>
  );
}
```

I didn't have to use the next-redux-wrapper package, just the usual react-redux and @reduxjs/toolkit, link to documentation: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/endpoints